# Select Max number from column doesnt return max

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running a sql query to return the largest value in a column back to the program.

The sql query i run is..

```
select MAX([Line No]) from table
```

I am using sql server 2008.

The table has 3 rows, 'Line No' has values 50, 90, 100

the max value i expect to be returned is 100,
but im getting 90..why?

EDIT:

```
  string LineNo = "0";

   //LineNo
   string SQLlineno = "select MAX(CAST([Line No] As Int)) from Saved_Order_Import where [order no] = '"
                      + ordernumber + "'";
   SqlCommand myCommandlineno = new SqlCommand(SQLlineno, myConnection);
   SqlDataReader readerline;
   try
   {
       readerline = myCommandlineno.ExecuteReader();
       if (readerline.HasRows)
       {
           while (readerline.Read())
           {
               try
               {
                   if (readerline.GetString(0) != null)
                   {
                       LineNo = (readerline.GetString(0) + 10).ToString();
                   }
               }
               catch (Exception ex) { return "{\"error\":\"line : " + ex.ToString() + "\"}"; }
           }
       }
       readerline.Close();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      // return "{\"error\":\"Other One11" + ex.ToString() + "\"}";
   }
```

Comment: See my update on `ExecuteScalar`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your column is likely not a numeric type but a string type (char, nchar, varchar, nvarchar). So, it is sorting alphabetically, and 9 comes after 1.

The easiest thing is to change to the correct data type for that column. If you can't do that, you'll need to cast back to the correct type inside the `MAX`.

E.g.,

```
select max(cast ([Line No] as int)) 
from table
```

If you have some values in that column that cannot be converted to a number that you want to filter out, you can do:

```
select max(cast ([Line No] as int)) 
from table 
where isnumeric([Line No]) = 1
```

Or, to only show the non-numeric values, so you can fix them, you could do:

```
select *
from table 
where isnumeric([Line No]) = 0
```

For more robust integer detection, see this article: [Can I Convert This String to an Integer?](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/can-i-convert-this-string-to-an-integer-)

Comment: Ah yes it is string type! any suggestion on what query i could use instead then? i can not change the data type of the column

Comment: `select MAX(CAST([Line No] as int)) from table` should do the trick.

Comment: @Beginner see my update above on how you can filter out the bad values

Comment: I think its because i am still doing reader.getstring instead of int?

Comment: The error message should be giving you a clue. (Unless you are eating it, like in your code above...)

Answer (score 1):

```
select MAX(cast([Line No] as int)) from table
```

**UPADTE:**
Call the `ExecuteScalar` on your `SqlCommand` not `GetSring`.

```
int max = (int)myCommandlineno.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values

Answer (score 0):

As RedFilter's answer,it may be a different type. Cast the column value to a numeric type and then apply the Max function

```
select MAX(CAST(LineNo AS INT) from table
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the numeric maximium from text data, you have to cast the values:

```
select max(cast([Line No] as int)) from table
```

Comment: That's beacuse it's an integer now, not a string. Use `GetInt32` to get the value. Also, to check for null values you should use the `IsDbNull` method, not compare a value to `null`. The database driver never returns `null` values, it returns `DbNull` values.

Answer (score 0):

If you have other alphanumeric values in your column that cannot be converted to int, and you want to ignore them, but you still want to return a string to the code, you can do something like this:

```
select cast(max(cast(LineNo AS int) as varchar(10))
from table
where isnumeric([LineNo] = 1)
```

However, if the column is intended to hold integers, I recommend you schedule some development time to change the column type and migrate any non-integers to acceptable values.  You can really get yourself into trouble if you don't use proper data types.